Relationship between major and minor axis of an ellipse's circumference
I'm not a mathematician. I'm just doing 3D modeling and can't find an equation to solve this problem. In openscad, an ellipse is created by scaling a circle.  So this code creates an ellipse with a major axis length of $2$, and a minor axis length $1$ from a circle of diameter $1$.
scale(x=1,y=2) circle(d=1);

What I'm looking for is a formula $f(y) = x$ such that the circumference stays the same.  IOW what should my $x$ scale be given a $y$ scale (where $0 < y < \pi/2$) so that my perimeter/circumference remains equal to $\pi$ in the resulting ellipse.
If it helps, this post
Proving relationship between major and minor radius of ellipse of constant radius
seems to contain a form of the answer.
$$
\pi^b=\frac{(2\pi-2)a+2-\pi^2}{2-\pi}
$$
Unfortunately I don't have the background to turn it into an equation of the $x=$ (or in that case $b=$) form I need.
UPDATE:
As the comments below note, the referenced page and formula above don't work.  Ignore them.
It seems I was negligent in emphasizing and making clear certain constraints as to what makes an answer useful to ME as opposed to random people looking at the title (who probably WANT ser170231's answer).
I'm looking for a formula that doesn't require more than basic arithmetic, logs, exponents and trig functions so I can implement it in a modeling program I'm using to build various versions of an object to be 3D printed.  Something that requires recursion or iterative processing is OK.  I need at least 4, and ideally 5, significant digits of precision in the resulting circumference match.
Comments suggest using an approximation formula but it's frustratingly difficult to find one that does what I need much less describes it's accuracy in enough detail to tell if it's results meet my accuracy needs.  I'm perfectly willing to entertain using 2 or 3 different methods for different ranges of a/b ratio to reach my goal.  What I'm hoping for is for someone who understands the limitations of various methods to suggest something specific.

Presumably a downvote means there is something wrong with the question however it's impossible to correct the issue if there is no comment explaining what is wrong?

Solving this problem will likely require elliptic integrals. Do you have any background in calculus? (not the down/close voter)

I wouldn't worry too much about the downvote, this seems like a fine question to me. The exact behavior of the circumference of an ellipse turns out to be surprisingly complicated (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference). Would you be okay with an approximation?

That formula, unfortunately, doesn't work (just tested with GeoGebra).

I realized that most of that formula evaluated to constants and that either value could be a or b so I solved for a where a and b were both 1 (a circle) and saw it didn't work.  Thanks.  An approximation is as good as it can get because I need to code it in openscad which can only do fairly basic math.

This reminds me of this Numberphile video: Why is there no equation for the perimeter of an ellipse‽

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, the perimeter of an ellipse is given by an elliptic integral of the second kind. There are several different notation conventions used for these integrals, which can be a bit confusing.
The perimeter $P$ of an ellipse with semimajor axis $a$ and semiminor axis $b$ is given by the elliptic integral:
$$P = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2\theta^2 + b^2\cos^2\theta^2} d\theta$$
Note that this is equivalent to
$$P = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2\theta^2 + b^2\sin^2\theta^2} d\theta$$
It's usual to write this in terms of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind:
$$E(m) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - m\sin^2\theta^2} d\theta$$
Let $m=1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}$, which is the square of the eccentricity of the ellipse. Also, let $m'=1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}$, which is the square of the second eccentricity of the ellipse.
Then the quarter perimeter of the ellipse is
$$Q = a E(m) = b E(m')$$
So if we know the eccentricity, it's easy to compute $a$ and $b$ for a given perimeter. However, if we're just given one of the semi-axes and the perimeter, we need to invert the elliptic integral to determine the eccentricity. There isn't a simple equation for that, but it can be done numerically, using Newton's method. That requires the derivative of $E(m)$, which is a function composed of $E(m)$ and $K(m)$, the complete elliptic integral of the first kind:
$$K(m) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 - m\sin^2\theta^2}}$$
$$\frac{dE(m)}{dm} = \left( E(m) - K(m)\right) / 2m$$
Elliptic integrals are available in advanced mathematics libraries, but they are not usually found in the standard libraries of most programming languages. Fortunately, they are very easy to compute to high precision, using the arithmetic-geometric mean (AGM), which converges quadratically. The AGM algorithm for $E(m)$ also computes $K(m)$ at the same time, so there's no extra work involved in computing the derivative of $E(m)$.
Newton's method (which also converges quadratically) requires an initial approximate solution, which it then refines. Fortunately, we can get a good initial approximation via the semicubic mean radius formula. Let $R$ be the mean radius of the ellipse. Then
$$R^{3/2} \approx \left(a^{3/2} + b^{3/2}\right)/2$$
This formula is quite good when the ratio between $a$ and $b$ is moderate. Here's a plot comparing the approximate $R$ to the true value computed using $E(m)$, for pairs of $a,b$ where $a+b=1$

It's excellent in the middle of the range, and it's still ok when $a=0.9, \, b=0.1$.
Here's a plot showing the mean radius computed using $E(m)$ with $b$ ranging over $(0, \pi/4)$, which uses the above formula to approximate $a$ and thence $m$. The error towards the extremes of the range is only ~1%.

Right at the extremes, the calculations run into difficulties. As $m\to 1,\, K(m)\to \infty$. At $m=0, \, K(m)=E(m)=\pi/2$, which results in $0/0$ in the numerical calculation of the derivative there, (but the derivative itself is finite). In my experiments using standard double precision floating-point arithmetic (which has 53 bits of precision) the safe range for $b$ is $10^{-6} < b < \pi/4 - 10^{-3}$.

Here is some Python code which calculates $a$ given $b$ for an ellipse of perimeter $\pi$ (so its mean radius is $\frac12$). It only uses simple arithmetic operations and square roots. I've avoided fancy Python syntax, so it should be fairly easy to translate to other languages. (The only Pythonisms that I used are the ability for functions to return multiple values, and to assign multiple values in one statement).
Code
""" Ellipse with pi perimeter

    Given one ellipse semi-axis, b: 0 < b < pi/4,
    find the other semi-axis, a, such that the
    perimeter of the ellipse equals pi. That is,
    the mean radius of the ellipse == 1/2

    The mean radius r is approximately given by
    r^(3/2) = (a^(3/2) + b^(3/2)) / 2

    The ellipse perimeter P is given exactly by the
    complete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind, E(m).
    P/4 = a * E(1 - b^2/a^2) = b * E(1 - a^2/b^2)

    Uses Newton's method with complete elliptic integrals,
    which are calculated using the arithmetic-geometric mean.

    Written by PM 2Ring 2024.06.30
"""

from math import ceil, pi, sqrt

eps = 1.8189894e-12
isqrt2 = sqrt(1/2)

# Extended arithmetic-geometric mean
def AGM_ext(a, b, eps=eps):
    s, k = 0, 1
    c2 = a*a - b*b
    r = 2.7 * sqrt(eps)
    while True:
        print(".", end="")
        a, b = (a + b) / 2, sqrt(a * b)
        c = c2 / (4 * a)
        c2 = c * c
        s += k * c2
        if c < r * a:
            break
        k *= 2
    print()
    return (a + b) / 2, s

def pi_test():
    a, s = AGM_ext(1, isqrt2)
    print("pi", a * a / (1/4 - s), pi, sep="\n")

#pi_test()

# Complete elliptic integrals of the 1st & 2nd kinds
def ell_KE(m):
    x = sqrt(1 - m)
    u, v = (1, x) if abs(x) < 1 else (x, 1)
    a, s = AGM_ext(u, v)
    ell1 = pi/2 / a
    ell2 = (1 - m/2 - s) * ell1
    return ell1, ell2

def newt(Y, m):
    """ Invert Y = elliptic_ec(m) using Newton's method """
    for i in range(1, 9):
        ell1, ell2 = ell_KE(m)
        den = ell2 - ell1
        if den == 0:
            return 0
        dm = (Y - ell2) * 2*m / den
        m += dm
        print(f"{i}: {m} {dm:.3e}")
        if abs(dm) < eps: break
    return m

# min b ~= 1e-6, max b ~= pi/4 - 1e-3
def ell(b):
    # First approximation, using semicubic mean radius formula
    a = (isqrt2 - b**(3/2)) ** (2/3)
    m = 1 - (a/b)**2
    print(f"\n{b=}\n{a=}\n{m=}")

    m = newt(pi/4 / b, m)
    a = b * sqrt(1 - m)
    # Check quadrant length is pi/4
    ell1, ell2 = ell_KE(m)
    q = (4/pi) * b * ell2
    print(f"{a=} {q=}")
    return a

# Test
step = 0.025
hi = ceil(pi/4 / step)
for i in range(1, hi):
    b = i * step
    ell(b)


Here's a live version of the code running on the SageMathCell server. As you can see, each Newton's method call converges within 5 loops, and so does each AGM call.
Here's a small sample of results computed using that code:



b
a




0.050
0.77956523


0.100
0.76622830


0.150
0.74744095


0.200
0.72406498


0.250
0.69655496


0.300
0.66514312


0.350
0.62990727


0.400
0.59079342


0.450
0.54761089


0.500
0.50000000


0.550
0.44735739


0.600
0.38867492


0.650
0.32215807


0.700
0.24411228


0.750
0.14387825



Here are some ellipses computed using that code:

Here's the script that created the second approximate mean radius plot.

I don't know if what you seek can be accomplished without invoking calculus and special functions.
Assume everything is centered at the origin in the $x,y$ plane. The circle with radius $\dfrac12$ has circumference $\pi$, and we may parameterize it by
$$(x,y) = \left(\frac12 \cos t, \frac12 \sin t\right), t\in[0,2\pi]$$
By symmetry, its arc length is given by the integral
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} \, dt &= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}4} \, dt\\
&= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 dt & \text{(symmetry)}\\
&= \pi
\end{align*}$$
Now suppose we scale $y$ by some factor $a>1$. In order to preserve the arc length, we simultaneously scale $x$ by some factor $0<b<1$, thus transforming the circle to an ellipse with parametric equations
$$(x,y) = \left(\frac b2 \cos t, \frac a2 \sin t\right), t\in[0,2\pi]$$
where the coefficients $a,b$ satisfy
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{b^2\sin^2t}4 + \frac{a^2\cos^2t}4} \, dt \stackrel{\rm symmetry}= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{b^2\sin^2t+a^2\cos^2t} \, dt = \pi$$
Let's consider a concrete example by fixing $a=\dfrac32$ (i.e. scale y up by a factor of $50\%$). We want to find $b$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
\pi &= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{b^2\sin^2t+\frac94\cos^2t} \, dt \\
&= 2 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{\frac94 + \left(b^2-\frac94\right)\sin^2t } \, dt \\
&= 3 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \sqrt{1 - \left(1-\frac{4b^2}9\right)\sin^2t} \, dt \\
\implies \pi &= 3 \, E\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{4b^2}9}\right)
\end{align*}$$
where $E(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. Possibly a closed form for $b$ exists in terms of elliptic functions. Numerically, it's about $b\approx0.28775$; see WolframAlpha's perimeter calculation here.

I'm very sorry to see it's really that hard.  OpenScad doesn't have any serious mathematical abilities built in and my own are not much better.  Anything beyond basic trig and exponents are outside it's capabilities.  I managed to code the ability to approximate the circumference using the infinite sum formula with half integer factorials but only because I found some articles that broke it down into simple algebra I could implement.

I would then second QiaochuYuan's suggestion to use approximations. The formulas due to S.Ramanujan in the Wiki article are relatively simple, and applying them boils the problem down to solving or further approximating the roots to a quartic equation, such as this one
